# Laptop turning off due to positioning relative to another one

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware

I was working on a MacBook Pro which was placed on top of a closed MacBook Pro. There is a precise position where the screen turns black and the internet stops working. I can repeat this phenomenon again and again with always the same output.

[image]

On the .gif, you can see (if you stare a little bit) the laptop is on top of another closed laptop. At the beginning of the .gif, everything goes fine. Then I pulled the laptop just a little bit and the screen turns black when a precise position is found. When I pull the laptop a bit further everything turns back to normal.

**What is going on?**

Comment: Also http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/138678/why-does-placing-a-moto-x-on-my-macbook-turn-off-the-screen

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Magnets](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203315).

Sensors in the body of the awake MBP are detecting magnets in the lid of the closed MBP.  It thinks you've closed the lid, so it goes to sleep.